# Wy does the function time.time() not append to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, time

I'm creating an instruction program that prints out an instruction from column df['STEPS '] and when you press 'Q' it records the time in column df['RECORDED TIME '] and prints out the next instruction.

I am trying to append the value of time.time() directly to a pandas dataframe. However it always records the same value for time.time(). 
I have also appended the value to an array, to show the discrepancy in values.

```
df=pd.read_csv('Pro-data.csv') #import the data 

a=0 #variable storing input values
array=[] #trial array storing time value
for i in range (5):#(len(df['STEPS '])): #loop over steps shortened the  loop to 5 to try it out 
    print(df['STEPS '][]) # print the step you need to do
    a= input('Q for next step') #user input
    while a!='Q': #MOVE onto next step when we push Q
        a= input('Q for next step')
    df['RECORDED TIME '][i]=time.time()
    array.append(time.time())
```

These are the values I get out from the 
array

```
Out[32]: 
[1554306491.3479252,
1554306492.7853866,
1554306493.722859,
1554306494.4139996,
1554306495.446119]
```

while these are the values that it saves in

```
df['RECORDED TIME ']
Out[33]: 
1.554306e+09
1.554306e+09
1.554306e+09
1.554306e+09
1.554306e+09
```

In df it is saving always the same value for some reason.

Comment: did you try to substract two values ? Maybe it keeps correct values but only formats it incorrectly when it displays it. As I know in pandas you can define how to format values when it displays it.

Comment: df['RECORDED TIME '][1]==df['RECORDED TIME '][3]
Out[56]: False.  So you are probably right, how do I change the display then to make sure ?

Comment: Ok, thanks, I've checked by printing the whole value and they are different. It was just a display problem.

Comment: check `pandas.display.precision` and `pandas.display.float_format` in documentation for [options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html). If you use Jupyter Notebooke then see also `pandas.style.format` in documentation fo [styling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html)